# tailings of macroeconomic statistics

Tags: vocabulary

From Smart Cities by Anthony M. Townsend:
Instead of sifting through the tailings of macroeconomic statistics for clues about recent events, they can plug into a sensory infrastructure that shows what is happening in the real economy at a microscopic level, second by second.

What does "tailings" mean?
Thanks for response.

Answer (score 2):

**Tailings**

tailings, gravel, aggregate, etc., or other residue of a product, as in mining; 
leavings.

[tailings](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tailings)

Here it is used in a figurative sense, meaning: instead of esamining what is left to consider in the macroeconomic statistics, ...

Comment: Was meint “esamining”?